# Vectorization of remainder loops by C++ compilers

Tags: c++, vectorization

Given a C++ function:

```
double myFunction(int n)
{

double A[n];
for(int i = 0;i<n;++i)
{
A[i] = 1.0;
}
return A[2];
}
```

If function 'myFunction' is compiled using intel C++ compilers, then the for loop will be vectorized by the compiler for a vector register word length 'N'.
However, there can be a remainder loop that exists if the number of iterations of the loop, n is NOT a multiple of N.

I have observed in the compiler optimization reports that the compiler can also vectorize the remainder loop but fail to understand how could that be possible.

**How are the remainder loops vectorized by C++ compilers?**

The remainder loop was not vectorized when the function above was compiled by intel compilers for SSE instruction set. However, the remainder loop was vectorized when compiled for AVX-512 instruction set.

Comment: can you include the compiler output you are refering to in the question?

Comment: [C++ doesn't have variable-length arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1887097/why-arent-variable-length-arrays-part-of-the-c-standard). Use `std::vector` instead.

Comment: Aside: I would expect a compiler to emit the equivalent to `double myFunction(int){ return 1.0; }` for that function.